# System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

I cannot manage to get the session working.

When I try to access the Session-Instance in a Page via:

`HttpContext.Session.Set("JWToken", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(user.Token));`

I get this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request.

I think I configured it correctly....

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();
        byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("SUPERSECRETKEYFORJWT");

        services.AddJwtBearerAuthentication(key);
        services.AddScoped<IAuthenticationService<User>, UserService>();
        services.AddMvc()
           .SetCompatibilityVersion(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
           .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
           {
               options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
               options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
           });
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options => 
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".supportcockpit";
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });            
}

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();            
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();            
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();                
        });
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("call to middleware");
            if (context.Session.TryGetValue("JWToken", out byte[] tokenBytes))
            {
                string token = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tokenBytes);
                context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            }
            await next();
        });
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();           
}
```

Comment: Your middleware registration order is a bit messed up. Your _specific_ problem is that `UseSession` needs to be before any middleware that uses it.

Comment: I only use it at 2 positions. In my LoginPage and the middleware you see above. The the first breakpoint hit is in the LoginPage. It should have been set up by then

Comment: You need `app.UseSession` _before_ `app.UseEndpoints` in your `Startup.Configure` method.

Comment: @KirkLarkin great! That works. How did you know?

Comment: It's just how middleware works, but actually your specific problem is mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configure-session-state) (first line under the code snippet).

Comment: right .. thanks for your help!